# how to plot real time graph using matplot

Tags: python

I am very new in python programming recently working on a project related to motion detection after detecting the motion my python script print mean deference of two frame  and detect motion and print the values in real time like this with

```
print mean
 0.655186631944
 0.305004340278
 0.927682291667
 0.220682508681
 0.470944010417
 0.521220703125
 0.789696180556
 0.316413845486
 0.490614149306
```

i have write down some code with help of some tutorials like this (here i have omitted the upper part of the code)

```
if mean >= threshold:
    counter = counter+1 
    #print "Motion Detected"
    print mean
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    def animate(i):
        ax1.clear()
        ax1.plot(counter,mean)
        ani = animation.FuncAnimaton(fig,animate, interval=1000)
        plt.show()
```

but this code is not working for me i want to plot a real time graph with function of time 
 please help.

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Its generating blank graph without any line